# How to efficiently paste many variables into a sql query (Rshiny)

Tags: sql, r, database, shiny, dbi

I'm building a shiny app where the user could update a table in a database by editing a selected row in a DT:table.

The problem is that process can be time-consuming when the dt:table has many columns (let's say 25 for instance). So I was wondering if there was a nice and efficient way to link my "vals" variables in the query below with the dataframe columns ?

The code below is working but since my DT:table has more than 60 columns I really cannot stick to this solution... :(

```
selected_row <- donnees[input$dt_rows_selected,]

query <- glue_sql('UPDATE myschema.mytable SET field1= ({vals*}), field2= ({vals2*}), field3 = ({vals3*}), field4= ({vals4*}), field5= ({vals5*}) WHERE id IN ({ID_field*});',
                          vals = selected_row$column1, vals2 = selected_row$column2, vals3= selected_row$column3, vals4= selected_row$column4, vals5= selected_row$column5, ID_field= selected_row$ID, .con = pool)
    
DBI::dbExecute(pool2, query)
```

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular questions should have complete reproducible examples including all inputs.  Please provide the input using `dput` as asked for there so anyone can run this in their R session.

Comment: I think an `UPSERT` operation might be better for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952425/updating-a-table-using-dataframes-and-dbsendquery in case it helps. Upserts are implemented differently for each DBMS (not supported by all), and does not have a respective function in `DBI`, so you'll need to fashion that query manually. Once you do that, however, I believe it will be faster/more-efficient and easier to work with. (The link discusses sql server, others are available with simple googling :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @r2evans, I didn't know about UPSERT and it could be useful for others scripts I'm working on ! :)
However I don't think it's the most efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to do here since I have to write down all the variable names in the sql query :( . But maybe I'm looking for something that cannot be done efficiently with R

Comment: Why do you have to write down all over the variables? Or why is that a problem? You're already hard-coding them in your query above. If you want to do it programmatically, that's rather simple too. Bottom line, it's not difficult to dynamically formulate the query for an upsert op. (If your DBMS is one that I know and have access to, I can craft a quick sample.)

Comment: It's a problem because in my real shiny app I would like to enable the user to update any column in the DT:table but it has 61 columns (I only wrote down 5 to illustrate my example). I would like to find a far more efficient way to do that without having to write every single variable in R. Maybe it's feasible with a loop ?

Comment: No. Really, use upsert. 61 columns changes nothing. If you want efficient, then the query needs to be created dynamically based on the columns that change, so we're already in the camp of having to do things programmatically. Over to you, though. If you want this help, I have an idea but will do nothing without knowing the database type.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer ! I'm gonna try to play with dt_cells_selected to update the table in the databased based on the modified columns of the dt:table then !

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to my problem in the end...  If you have still a bit of time and want to provide me a quick example as you kindly proposed yesterday @r2evans : my DBMS is Postgresql :)

Comment: This solution: stackoverflow.com/questions/63406355/… could have worked with an "INSERT" but I can't manage to adapt it to an UPDATE

Comment: As I said before ... DBMSes implement the "UPSERT" thought differently; that mssql solution won't work for psql.

Comment: @zakros, see my answer, I think it gives you a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this answer is two-fold:

- Demonstrate the (a?) proper postgres-style upsert action. I present a `pg_upsert` function, and in that function I've included (prefixed with `#'#`) what the query looks like when finished. The query is formed dynamically, so does not need a priori knowledge of the fields other than the user-provided `idfields=` argument.
- Demonstrate how to react to `DT`-edits using this function. This is one way and there are definitely other ways to formulate how to deal with the reactive `DT`. If you have a different style for keeping track of changes in the `DT`, then feel free to take `pg_upsert` and run with it!

Notes:

- it does not update the database with each cell edit, the changes are "batched" until the user clicks the `Upsert!` button; it is feasible to change to "upsert on each cell", but that would be a relatively trivial query, no need for upserts
- since you're using postgres, the target table must have one or more unique indices (see [No unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42022362/3358272)); I'll create the sample data and the index on said table; if you don't understand what this means and your data doesn't have a clear "id" field(s), then do what I did: add an `id` column (both locally and in the db) that sequences along your real rows (this won't work if your data is preexisting and has no id fields)
- the id field(s) *must not be editable*, so the `editable=` part of DT disables changing that column; I included a query (found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213199/3358272) that will tell you these fields programmatically; if this returns nothing, then go back to the previous bullet and fix it
- the `pg_upsert` function takes a few steps to ensure things are clean (i.e., checks for duplicate `id`s), but does not check for incorrect new-values (`DT` does some of this for you, by `class` I believe), I'll assume you are verifying what you need before sending for an upsert;
- the return value from `pg_upsert` is logical, indicating that the upsert action updated as many rows as we expected; this *might* be overly aggressive, though I cannot think of an example when it would correctly return other than `nrow(value)`; caveat emptor
- I include an *optional* `"dbout"` table in the shiny layout solely to show the current state of the database data, updated every time `pg_upsert` is called (indirectly); if no changes have been made, it will still query to show the current state, and is therefore the best way to show the starting condition for your testing; again, it is optional. When you remove it (and you should) and nothing else uses the `do_update()` reactive, then change

  ```r
  do_update <- eventReactive(input$upbtn, ...)
  output$dbout <- renderTable({ do_update(); ... })
  ```

  to

  ```r
  observeEvent(input$upbtn, ...)
  # output$dbout <- renderTable({ do_update(); ... })
  ```

  (Otherwise, a `reactive(.)` block that is never used downstream will never fire, so your updates would not happen.)
- *This* app queries the database for all values (into `curdata`), this is likely already being done in your case. This app also finds (programmatically) the required indices. If you know ahead of time what these are, feel free to drop the query that feeds `idfields` and just assign it directly (case-sensitive).
- When the app exits, the user-edited data is not stored in the local R console/environment, all changes are stored in the database. It's my assumption that this will be formalized into a `shiny-server`, RStudio Connect, or similar production server, in which case "console" has little meaning. If you really need the user-changed data to be available on the local R console while you are developing your app, then in addition to using `mydata` reactive values, after `mydata$data` is reassigned you can overwrite `curdata <<- mydata$data` (note the double `<` in `<<-`). I discourage this practice in production but it might be useful while in development.

Here is a setup for sample data. It doesn't matter if you have 6 (as here) or 60 columns, the premise remains. (After this, `origdata` is not used, it was a throw-away to prep for this answer.)

```r
# pgcon <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
set.seed(42)
origdata <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 6),]
origdata$id <- seq_len(nrow(origdata))
# setup for this answer
DBI::dbExecute(pgcon, "drop table if exists mydata")
DBI::dbWriteTable(pgcon, "mydata", origdata)
# postgres upserts require 'unique' index on 'id'
DBI::dbExecute(pgcon, "create unique index mydata_id_idx on mydata (id)")
```

Here is the UPSERT function itself, broken out to facilitate testing, console evaluation, and similar.

```r
#' @param value 'data.frame', values to be updated, does not need to
#'   include all columns in the database
#' @param name 'character', the table name to receive the updated
#'   values
#' @param idfields 'character', one or more id fields that are present
#'   in both the 'value' and the database table, these cannot change
#' @param con database connection object, from [DBI::dbConnect()]
#' @param verbose 'logical', be verbose about operation, default true
#' @return logical, whether 'nrow(value)' rows were affected; if an
#'   error occurred, it is messaged to the console and a `FALSE` is
#'   returned
pg_upsert <- function(value, name, idfields, con = NULL, verbose = TRUE) {
  if (verbose) message(Sys.time(), " upsert ", name, " with ", nrow(value), " rows")
  if (any(duplicated(value[idfields]))) {
    message("'value' contains duplicates in the idfields, upsert will not work")
    return(FALSE)
  }
  tmptable <- paste(c("uptemp_", name, "_", sample(1e6, size = 1)), collapse = "")
  on.exit({
    DBI::dbExecute(con, paste("drop table if exists", tmptable))
  }, add = TRUE)
  DBI::dbWriteTable(con, tmptable, value)
  cn <- colnames(value)
  quotednms <- DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, cn)
  notid <- DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, setdiff(cn, idfields))
  qry <- sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO %s ( %s )
     SELECT %s FROM %s
     ON CONFLICT ( %s ) DO
     UPDATE SET %s",
    name, paste(quotednms, collapse = " , "),
    paste(quotednms, collapse = " , "), tmptable,
    paste(DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(con, idfields), collapse = " , "),
    paste(paste(notid, paste0("EXCLUDED.", notid), sep = "="), collapse = " , "))
  #'# INSERT INTO mydata ( "Sepal.Length" , "Petal.Length" )
  #'#      SELECT "Sepal.Length" , "Petal.Length" , "id" FROM mydata
  #'#      ON CONFLICT ( "id" ) DO
  #'#      UPDATE SET "Sepal.Length"=EXCLUDED."Sepal.Length" , "Petal.Length"=EXCLUDED."Petal.Length"
  # dbExecute returns the number of rows affected, this ensures we
  # return a logical "yes, all rows were updated" or "no, something
  # went wrong"
  res <- tryCatch(DBI::dbExecute(con, qry), error = function(e) e)
  if (inherits(res, "error")) {
    msg <- paste("error upserting data:", conditionMessage(res))
    message(Sys.time(), " ", msg)
    ret <- FALSE
    attr(ret, "error") <- conditionMessage(res)
  } else {
    ret <- (res == nrow(value))
    if (!ret) {
      msg <- paste("expecting", nrow(value), "rows updated, returned", res, "rows updated")
      message(Sys.time(), " ", msg)
      attr(ret, "error") <- msg
    }
  }
  ret
}
```

Here's the shiny app. When you source this, you can immediately press `Upsert!` to get the current state of the database table (again, only an option, not required for production), no updated values are needed to requery.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

pgcon <- DBI::dbConnect(...) # fix this incomplete expression

curdata <- DBI::dbGetQuery(pgcon, "select * from mydata order by id")
# if you don't know the idfield(s) offhand, then use this:
idfields <- DBI::dbGetQuery(pgcon, "
  select
      t.relname as table_name,
      i.relname as index_name,
      a.attname as column_name
  from
      pg_class t,
      pg_class i,
      pg_index ix,
      pg_attribute a
  where
      t.oid = ix.indrelid
      and i.oid = ix.indexrelid
      and a.attrelid = t.oid
      and a.attnum = ANY(ix.indkey)
      and t.relkind = 'r'
      and t.relname = 'mydata'
  order by
      t.relname,
      i.relname;")
idfieldnums <- which(colnames(curdata) %in% idfields$column_name)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput("tbl"),
    actionButton("upbtn", "UPSERT!"),
    tableOutput("dbout")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    mydata <- reactiveValues(data = curdata, changes = NULL)

    output$tbl = renderDT(
      mydata$data, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE),
      editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = idfields)))

    observeEvent(input$tbl_cell_edit, {
      mydata$data <- editData(mydata$data, input$tbl_cell_edit)
      mydata$changes <- rbind(
        if (!is.null(mydata$changes)) mydata$changes,
        input$tbl_cell_edit
      )
      # keep the most recent change to the same cell
      dupes <- rev(duplicated(mydata$changes[rev(seq(nrow(mydata$changes))),c("row","col")]))
      mydata$changes <- mydata$changes[!dupes,]
      message(Sys.time(), " pending changes: ", nrow(mydata$changes))
    })

    do_update <- eventReactive(input$upbtn, {
      if (isTRUE(nrow(mydata$changes) > 0)) {
        # always include the 'id' field(s)
        # idcol <- which(colnames(mydata$data) == "id")
        updateddata <- mydata$data[ mydata$changes$row, c(mydata$changes$col, idfieldnums) ]
        res <- pg_upsert(updateddata, "mydata", idfields = "id", con = pgcon)
        # clear the stored changes only if the upsert was successful
        if (res) mydata$changes <- mydata$changes[0,]
      }
      input$upbtn
    })

    output$dbout <- renderTable({
      do_update() # react when changes are attempted, the button is pressed
      message(Sys.time(), " query 'mydata'")
      DBI::dbGetQuery(pgcon, "select * from mydata order by id")
    })

  }
)
```

In action:

- (Left) When we start, we see the original `DT` and no database output.
- (Middle) Press the `Upsert!` button just to query the db and show the optional table.
- (Right) Make updates, then press `Upsert!`, and the database is updated (and the lower table re-queried).

[image: three screenshots, progress of this shiny app]

Comment: Wooow thank you so much for the detailled answer ! I will go through your explanations a bit later on ! It's fascinating and frustrating at the same time to see how people like you excel in programming xD !